# how do I delete geometry with proximity?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am trying to use this empty cube to delete these cubes and whenever I try to use location to delete geometry it doesn't work[image]

[image]

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking without images of your settings. Please use the [edit] link at the 
bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add 
more information on how you set up your project.
[Add images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) that 
might help us understand your scene and settings. See [How to upload 
an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491).

Comment: alright, I didn't know it was vague

Comment: You can't "just" use location to delete the geometry. You can however plug a Vector Math node set to Distance and then a math node set to Lower than and set your desired value there. Plug it between the Location output and the Selection input

Comment: Thanks, but I gotta play with it a bit to make it work how I want it

Comment: It's not just as easy as @Gorgious described and it also depends on what you want. For example, the _Vector Math_ node also needs a _Position_ node plugged in and your _Delete Geometry_ node has to be set to _Instances_ if you want to delete complete cubes (assuming from your question) without loose edges or vertices remaining - but then you can't use _Realize Instances_ beforehand or it won't work. The other thing is, _Distance_ deletes spherical around the cube's origin. If you want _Delete Geometry_ to take the cube's shape into account, you need _Mesh Boolean_ (cutting the cubes as well).

Comment: (I was running out of space) If you don't want _Mesh Boolean_ to cut the small cubes in "fragments" but delete complete cubes instead, then you would have to use _Mesh Boolean_ earlier on the geometry which is used to distribute the points.

Comment: i am not sure whether you understood the "selection": it is just a boolean, so it just takes two values: either 0 or 1. So plugging a location into a selection makes no sense.

Answer (score 10):

If you want simply to delete instances, or geometry such as vertices, by distance from an Empty, there is no need for the (quite pricey) *Geometry Proximity* node. You can just use the *Distance* between the Empty's location and *Position*

[image]

.. if you mean spherical distance.

[image]

If you want cubic distance, you have to test against X,Y, and Z independently, one way or another:

[image]

like so:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Geometry proximity works like this:

[image]

Note: Geometry proximity is called "geometry proximity" because it needs geometry, which means mesh in this case. It does not work with empties.

result:

[image]

```
Note: Geometry Proximity also means, not only it needs geometry but it also only works where there is geometry. This means (of course depending on the threshold distance) that there are (or could be) instances reappearing inside the sphere.
```

Comment: You should mention that _Geometry Proximity_ also means, not only it needs geometry but it also only works where there is geometry. In your above example I assume the sphere is hollow - no geometry inside. This means (of course depending on the threshold distance) that there are (or could be) instances reappearing inside the sphere. Which is no problem if the sphere covers them, but if you use invisible objects to remove something "magically", then they will show up (which is why I mentioned _Mesh Boolean_ in my above comments to get rid of them). But still: +1

Comment: thanks, added that to the answer