# Is it possible to make an array modifier "fan out"?

Tags: modifiers

[image]

In this picture the first row has 5 and the last row has 15 seats. Is it possible to use two array modifiers to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to do that with just Array modifiers, but it should be possible with geometry nodes. I put together an example with making a grid and removing values to far away from an empty:

[image: geometry nodes setup]

Additional details on technique I used: "[how do I delete geometry with proximity?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/256467/how-do-i-delete-geometry-with-proximity)"

Comment: If only the array mod were a node that could be driven with values. ;)  Maybe someday...